# AssertionError - Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am creating a Python script with Selenium. I want to run a specific test that checks the default text of a textbox when the page loads up. Below is my code.......

```
try: 
                    self.assertEqual("Search by template name or category..", sel.get_text("//table[@id='pluginToolbarButton_forms']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/em"))
                    logging.info('      PASS:  text box text is correct')
                except Exception:
                    logging.exception('     FAIL: text box text is incorrect')
```

Here is my error......

```
            self.assertEqual("Search by template name or category..", sel.get_text("//table[@id='pluginToolbarButton_forms']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/em"))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 509, in assertEqual
    assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 502, in _baseAssertEqual
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: 'Search by template name or category..' != u'Submitter Requests'
```

Am I using the wrong function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AssertionError` states that the assertion you tried (that's the `self.assertEqual(...)` in your first code example) failed:

```
AssertionError: 'Search by template name or category..' != u'Submitter Requests'
```

This assertion explains that the string `'Search by template name or category'` is different from `'Submitter Requests'`, which is correct ... the strings *are*, in fact, different.

I would check your second parameter to `self.assertEqual` and make sure that you're selecting the right feature.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are using the right function, but perhaps you are not running your tests in the correct fashion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are not selecting the right element to compare with. You are basically telling the program to match that "Search by template name or category.." is equal to the contents of whatever is in:

```
//table[@id='pluginToolbarButton_forms']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/em
```

Apparently, the contents are "Submitter Requests", i.e not what you would expect, so the test fails (as it should). You might not be selecting the right element with that XPath query. Maybe a CSS query would be best. You can read about element selectors in the [Selenium documentation](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html).

Keep an eye open for a pitfall as well: the text returned by Selenium is a [Unicode object](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type), and you are comparing it against a string. This might not work as expected on special characters.